# swfobject.embedSWF Not displaying video

Tags: javascript, php, video, youtube

This isn't making the youtube video show up on page and I don't know why this is happening?

```
    <div id="ytPlayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/Some-random-video?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", "ytPlayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
    </script>
```

Comment: YouTube provides [**embed codes**](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

According to the new [swfobject page](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject) on github, the syntax for embedding has changed slightly.

Example given:

> Old:
>
> ```
>  swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "my-target-element", "300", "120", "10.0.0");
> ```
>
> New
>
> ```
> var el = document.getElementById("my-target-element");
> swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", el, 300, 120, 10);
> ```

I'm unsure how this works with URLs but it does look like your embed script needs a bit of tweaking.

As Flash is on the decline, perhaps it's worth considering converting your file to a standard video format and using HTML5 video tags? Just a suggestion..

Hope this helps

Comment: How would I do that? You have to excuse my bluntness but I bought a script thinking that it all worked and find out I have to fix this mess. I believe you in when you say it's out dated and that's probably why I'm having so many errors in other parts of the script. If you know your stuff and could fix these errors I could pay you at a later date.

Comment: how would you do what? convert the file? there are quite a few converters out there but only a few good ones. The one i use is one by Moyea I think. I'll double check the make. It's also purchased but it's not an online convert, you download the software

Comment: it's on my other computer. I'm fairly sure that's the make. Most of the other ones come with a watermark

Comment: I'll see if I can get back to you, still working this code out. I just need to embed these youtube videos, for some reason the programmer used flash to embed them. The script is ugly disorganized code I just have to figure out how it works. It's part of a social exchange youtube plugin. of course I'm pretty sure all the plugins are shot/outdated that were provided in the program, at least all the ones I've tested today.

Comment: There are plugins available also. Search for flash converter or flash detector plugins on Google. I'm sure there's some on github. Definitely worth a look!

Comment: It's after 2am here.. I can't do any more tonight! Tomorrow I'll have another look, time-allowing.. I'm sure there's a good solution out there.

Comment: Excellent. What did you use? I've only just woken up! Half 6!